# Staging Env: Password protect everything except for webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, middleware, staging

For staging, I'd like to password protect everything so I added the code below.  However, how can I edit this so it will skip over the webhook controller so I can still test inbound emails on staging?

```
  config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Lock, "::Rack::Auth::Basic", "Staging") do |u, p|
    [u, p] == [ENV["STAGING_USERNAME"], ENV["STAGING_PASSWORD"]]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `Rack::Auth::Basic'. However, looking at the [source](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb), it seems that you can create your own simple authentication mechanism that takes an extra option.

It's the same as `Rack::Auth::Basic`, except for the `call` method. Create a file called `authenticate_excluding.rb` in `app/middleware` with the following:

```
class AuthenticateExcluding < ::Rack::Auth::Basic

  def initialize(app, options={}, &authenticator)
    @excluded_paths = options[:exclude]
    super(app, options[:realm], &authenticator)
  end

  def call(env)
    if @excluded_paths && @excluded_paths.include?(env['PATH_INFO'])
      return @app.call(env)
    end
    super
  end
end
```

You can now use it with:

```
config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Lock, "AuthenticateExcluding", excluding: ["/webhooks/service", "/other_hook"]) do |u, p|
  [u, p] == [ENV["STAGING_USERNAME"], ENV["STAGING_PASSWORD"]]
end
```

That should work. If you also want to enable the realm (the previous "Staging" argument), you can also add `realm: "Staging"` to the options hash.

Comment: `env['PATH_INFO']` contains the path of the current request. Basically, the middleware checks whether the requested path is in its excluded list of paths and bypasses authentication if so.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with [rack/private](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rack-private) as you can specify an exception like so:

```
use Rack::Private, :code => ENV["STAGING_PASSWORD"] do
  except '/webhooks/service'
end
```

You can also specify HTTP methods as well if required.

The only problem is that you don't have a username AND password, just a secret code. I don't know if that meets your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could easily solve the issue by just including the staging username and password in the webhook URL.

```
If this URL requires HTTP Basic Auth, enter http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@YOUR_URL into the url field." - Codeship.io
```